# AttributeError: type object 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion._TSObject' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Tags: python, pandas, cython, attributeerror

I was working on a Jupyter Notebook on Firefox, when immediately I received a notification that I should update and upgrade my Ubuntu. Everything was working normal. However, when I restarted my laptop, as required after the update, and load the basic python modules as numpy, pandas, etc. I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-2a99f902fe48> in <module>
      3 
      4 # For database manipulation
----> 5 import pandas as pd
      6 #pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
      7 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>
     28 
     29 try:
---> 30     from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib
     31 except ImportError as e:  # pragma: no cover
     32     # hack but overkill to use re

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py in <module>
      1 # flake8: noqa
      2 
----> 3 from .tslibs import (
      4     NaT,
      5     NaTType,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/tslibs/__init__.py in <module>
      1 # flake8: noqa
      2 
----> 3 from .conversion import localize_pydatetime, normalize_date
      4 from .nattype import NaT, NaTType, iNaT, is_null_datetimelike
      5 from .np_datetime import OutOfBoundsDatetime

pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion()

AttributeError: type object 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion._TSObject' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

I checked on the internet for any advice, I restarted twice my laptop and I still get the same error. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Ultimately if this came from an Ubuntu update and it happens every time you try to import Pandas then you probably just need to wait for another Ubuntu update to fix it. You could check whether it happens outside Jupyter? Or you could try installing Pandas using Pip instead? This error has largely been fixed in recent versions of Cython (so Pandas may just need rebuilding) but is mostly related to circular imports/Cython modules that raise exceptions and are then re-imported

Comment: With that said, it looks like you're already going off a local install of Pandas so why not just remove and reinstall that?

Comment: I reinstalled pandas and the problem persists